# Schnorr signature security level as compared to AES/RSA

Tags: rsa, aes, finite-field, schnorr-signature

As per the Schnorr's original paper (1991),

> The Security Complexity $2^t$: We wish to choose the parameters $p$, $q$ so that forging a signature or an authentication requires about $2^t$ steps by known methods. For this we choose $q > 2^{2t}$ and $p$ such that $2^t$ is about $e^{\sqrt{\ln(p)\ln(\ln(p))}}$. ... For $p > 2^{512}$ and $q > 2^{140}$ the discrete logarithm problem requires at least $2^{72}$ steps by known algorithms.

Now I have three questions regarding this.

1. How does value of $p$ comes to $2^{512}$ for security complexity of $2^{72}$?
2. What is the equivalent AES and RSA key-lengths if we use $p$ of $1024$ bits and $q$ of $512$ bits?
3. Since Schnorr is finite field signature scheme, what is the '*field size*', '*group size*' and '*subgroup size*' in case of schnorr signature scheme?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does value of $p$ comes to $2^{512}$ for security complexity of
>   $2^{72}$?

Personally, I couldn't connfirm this number, but rather landed at $2^{66}$. If you don't know how to find this number, just plug the $2^{512}$ into the complexity equation given and take the logarithm to the base two for better readability.

Note that Schnorr's complexity estimate for the field is based on the [Index-Calculus Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index-calculus) and doesn't yet take into account the [Number Field Sieve (original paper as PDF)](http://www.ccrwest.org/gordon/log.pdf) against discrete logarithms, which would give a different expression, namely $L_p[1/3,3^{2/3}]=e^{(3^{2/3}+o(1))(\ln p)^{1/3}(\ln\ln p)^{2/3}}$, that would yield a much lower required attack complexity.

> What is the equivalent AES and RSA key-lengths if we use $p$ of $1024$
>   bits and $q$ of $512$ bits?

$q$ is the subgroup order and if you get a 512-bit subgroup you'll have roughly 256-bit security for this subgroup. $p$ is the field prime and with it being 1024-bit, you'll get roughly 80-bit security against NFS-based attacks. So the answer is: A 1024-bit RSA modulus will have a comparable security along with AES-128, where 48 key bits are constant zero'ed out. Note that just plugging-in $2^{1024}$ into the complexity equations is a dangerous business, as $o(1)$ hides an implementation-dependenant (constant) factor that was not accounted for. Rather you need a concrete data point as a basis for further extrapolation. Here's a more detailed treatment of keylengths: [(simple)](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/164539/files/NPDF-32.pdf) [(complex)](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/164526/files/NPDF-22.pdf) by Lenstra and Verheul.

> Since Schnorr is finite field signature scheme, what is the '*field
>   size*', '*group size*' and '*subgroup size*' in case of schnorr
>   signature scheme?

$p$ is the field prime and its bitlength is the field size.
$q$ is the subgroup order and its bitlength is the subgroup size.
There's no relevant *"group size"* in this case (maybe one could say that's equivalent to the field size though)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I got everything right, so complain as usual if something is wrong ;)

Comment: I didn't get why you told to get log to base 2 (ln means base should be e).

If I'm right, you considered lowest of 256 and 80-bit (i.e. 80-bit) as resultant security level. But as per schnorr's formula 1024-bit should give security level of 98-bits.

What is the formula to calculate security level against NFS-based attacks in case of p?

Comment: Now I understood what you intended to say when you told to take log to base 2. Its for final result of exponentiation which will give value of t directly. Please clarify about my second doubt in above comment.

Comment: @Maheshk, I used *"take the logarithm to the base two for better readability."* so you see $66$ and not $7.3789*10^{19}$ which is rather unhelpful in cryptography, the result of the logarithm will also be the $t$ value. I've added some treatment of NFS run-time.

Comment: I think in equation of Lp[1/3, 3^2/3], power of ln(p) should be 1/3 and power of ln(ln(p)) should be 2/3 as per formula of Lp in http://www.ccrwest.org/gordon/log.pdf. 
One more thing, I didn't find anything on O(1). How can I find value of O(1) based on my implementation?

Comment: @Maheshk, you need to run a factorization / discrete logarithm computation and measure the time. The "simple" linked paper then shows you how to proceed (the easiest way).

Comment: I will look into that paper. Thanks for your answer. It cleared all my doubts and also I had not considered newer attacks like NFS. Now my security estimate will be more safe. I'm marking ans as "accepted".